# Alert / Message at Service Eventlistener

Tags: symfony, pimcore-v5

I am working with Eventlisteners in Pimcore. In my Case I need an Alert / Message. It should be displayed if I upload an Asset twice.

My Events looks like:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;
use Pimcore\Event\Model\AssetEvent;
 ...
class AssetsEvent {
  public function onAssetPreAdd(AssetEvent $event) {
        $logger = ApplicationLogger::getInstance('ImageUpload', true);
        $asset = $event->getAsset();
 ....

 echo 'This is my …!';
}
```

If i use "echo ‘This is my …’; this works, but that could not be the right way and looks not fine. Is there a way to implemt JavaScript for “Alerts” or something?

Comment: Are Flash messages something you might consider? https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages

Comment: What do you mean by "implement JavaScript for Alerts"? Maybe provide a comparison of what you want to achieve, e.g. "a notification like in ...", or maybe a screenshot of how it looks now and what you want changed. It might also be helpful to see how your current implementation looks to be better able to judge if it it's "the right way" in the context of Symfony or Pimcore.

Comment: I have edit my post! Okay that addFlash() looks well but what are the correct use statements to use addFlash?